# htaccess redirect but exclude a given folder

Tags: .htaccess

I've taken over an old site that was setup using .html files in all the URLs.

```
e.g: http://www.mysite.com/contact-us.html
```

I've rebuilt the site to now have URLs like this:

```
e.g: http://www.mysite.com/contact-us/
```

Rather than creating dummy pages for all the many many many html files and because the client is complaining that search engine results now go to a 404, I've created a temporary .htaccess rule for the next few days that redirects any page requests made to an .html file with a 301 to the homepage.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://www.mysite.com/
```

The only problem is that I need to be able to exclude a particular folder from that rule as it contains a .html file that I'm not permitted to change.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/ur_restricted_folder/ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to do the trick. I'll carry on searching and experimenting and if I find a solution I will post it here.